# How to isolate Scottish spatial data in public dataset?

Tags: qgis, scotland

I want to get Scotland's Council Wards geospatial data. The [link on spatialdata.gov.scot](https://spatialdata.gov.scot/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/f17baa94-1e55-4656-9f7b-ead496609220) links to [OS Opendata Boundary line](https://osdatahub.os.uk/downloads/open/BoundaryLine). But that dataset is for the entire UK.

In that dataset is the shapefile data/gb/district_borough_unitary_ward_region.shp which I believe has the data I need. But when I look at the attribute table I see nothing to uniquely identify ward by country. How can I access only Scotlands electoral wards?

Comment: I'm using QGIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression to select Scotish wards `left( "CODE" , 1)='S'`

Or do it by spatial selection (which is the hard way I tried first.

I would use `scotland_and_wales_region_region.shp` to give me the outlines of Scotland and Wales. Then I would select Scotland in that layer, and then use `Select by Location` to find all the wards that are within or touch the selected polygon

[image]

This will give you all of Scotland and a strip of neighbours across the top of England that you can deselect by hand, you then need to `export` your selection to a new GeoPackage.

[image]